# Как правильнее сверстать подобный блок?

Tags: html, css, scss

В макете есть блок с карточками и таким эффектом при наведении

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сверстал его на `flex-box` таким образом:

html

```
<div class="works__items-row">
    <a class="works__item" href="">
       <img class="works__item-img" src="./images/works/01.png" alt="">
    </a>
    
    <a class="works__item" href="">
       <img class="works__item-img" src="./images/works/01.png" alt="">
    </a>
     class="works__items-row">
    <a class="works__item" href="">
       <img class="works__item-img" src="./images/works/01.png" alt="">
    </a>
    
    <a class="works__item" href="">
       <img class="works__item-img" src="./images/works/01.png" alt="">
    </a>
    
</div>
```

scss:

```
.works {
&__items-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &__item {
        flex-basis: 25%;
        max-width: $base * 120;
        max-height: $base * 120;
        
        background-color: $accent;
        background-image: url("../images/works/icon.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    &__item-img {
        flex: $base*120;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        transition: all .5s;

        &:hover {
            opacity: .6;
        }
    }
}
```

Но мне кажется, что вот так задавать `works__item` задний фон и управлять прозрачностью картинки решение слишком негибкое. Допустим, я захочу добавить вторую иконку скажем с лайками или количеством комментариев к работе и не смогу это сделать. Как в таком случае мне нужно переделать верстку?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.works__item {
  position: relative;
}

.works__item-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.works__item:hover .layer {
  opacity: 1;
}

.eye-icon {
  background-image: url("../images/works/icon.svg");
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%;
  -50%);
}
```

```html
<a class="works__item" href="">
  <div class="layer"><span class="eye-icon"></span></div>
  <img class="works__item-img" src="./images/works/01.png" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: хорошо, прошу прощения за сухой код, в общем у нас есть блок-ссылка, внутри которой абсолютом поставлена картинка и слой, который появляется при наведении

Answer (score 1):

Я бы выполнил следующим образом.

```css
.works {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.works .works__item {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% / 4); /* Т.е. 4 блока по ширине */
  position: relative;
  /* Уберём действия ссылки */
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.works .works__item::before { /* Хак, чтобы блок был квадратный пропорционально */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.works .works__item img,
.works .works__item::after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.works .works__item::after {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(51,71,119,.65) url('//i.imgur.com/LCgqjSx.png') no-repeat center center / 2em auto;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.works .works__item:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.works .works__item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/QbUlKak.png">
  </a>

  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/fXOr4pR.png">
  </a>

  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/QbUlKak.png">
  </a>

  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/fXOr4pR.png">
  </a>

  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/fXOr4pR.png">
  </a>

  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/QbUlKak.png">
  </a>

  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/fXOr4pR.png">
  </a>
  
  <a class="works__item" href="#">
    <img class="works__item-img" src="//i.imgur.com/QbUlKak.png">
  </a>
</div>
```